# ERROR: TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable i

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a problem when using multer to store a file coming from Front-end using rest api then store the path of that file in mySQL:

here is my code:

**route/front_id.js:**

```
   var express = require('express');
   var multer = require('multer');
   var router = express.Router();
   var front_idController = require("../app/controllers/front_idController")

   router.post("/", function(request, response, next){

   var storage = multer.diskStorage({

    destination:function(request, file, callback)
    {
        callback(null, './upload/front_id_image');
    
    },
    filename : function(request, file, callback)
    {
        var temp_file_arr = file.originalname.split(".");

        var temp_file_name = temp_file_arr[0];

        var temp_file_extension = temp_file_arr[1];
    
        callback(null, temp_file_name + Date.now() + '.' +temp_file_extension);
    }

});

var upload = multer({storage:storage}).array('front_id');

upload(request, response,async function(error){
    
   await front_idController (request.files[0].path, request.body.id);
    if(error)
    {
        return response.end('Error Uploading File'+ error);
    }
    else
    {
        return response.end('Files is uploaded successfully');
    };
  });

 });

 module.exports = router;
```

**controllers/front_idController.js**

```
const { Sequelize, sequelize } = require("../../database/connection");
const Info = require("../models/Info")(sequelize, Sequelize);

const front_idController = async (info, id) => {

    const [updatedRows] = await Info.update({
        front_id_image: info,
    }
        ,
        {
            where: { id: id }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
         if (updatedRows) {
                return (`Updated rows: ${updatedRows}`);
            } else {
                return "User not found";
            };

}



module.exports = front_idController
```

the problem occur when using `request.files[0].path` as an argument and pass it to front_idController to store it as a path of the file in database
but it getting this Error:

```
const [updatedRows] = await Info.update({
                      ^
```

> TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable
> at front_idController (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Github Project\valenci-backend\app\controllers\front_idController.js:6:27)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at async C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Github Project\valenci-backend\routes\front_id.js:34:8
>
> Node.js v18.12.1 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes
> before starting...

Comment: You don't seem to load the files correctly

Comment: @DreamBold the file uploaded correctly, but the problem when I want to pass the path from multer storage then store it in database

Comment: the only problem when passing  "request.files[0].path" to the controller and store it in datatbase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to **StefH** answer in [Async/await not working? #782](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/782)

the problem was in the bracket in

```
const [updatedRows] = await Info.update({
```

I did change it to:

```
const updatedRows = await Info.update({
```